# Convergence pointwise of positive functions and convergence in $L^{1}(X)$ implies convergence in $L^{1}(\text{measble subset})$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f_{n}, f \geq 0$ be measurable on a measure space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ with $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ pointwise, and $\int f_{n} \rightarrow \int f < \infty$. Show that $\int_{E} f_{n} \rightarrow \int_{E} f$ for all measurable $E$.

**What I've Tried:** I tried using Egorov's theorem and found a (false) solution, only to realize later that $\mu$ isn't necessarily finite. Now I'm stuck. I want $\int_{E} |f_{n} - f| d\mu$ to be small. It's at most $\int |f_{n} - f| d\mu$, but that's maybe not so helpful. I feel a little silly I can't solve this seemingly easy problem... a hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The question title is misleading: you are not assuming that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1(X)$. Instead, you are assuming that $\int_X f_n \to \int_X f$ which is a much weaker assumption.

Comment: @User8128: Under the other given assumptions, it is actually equivalent.

Comment: Sure sure, we could prove that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1(X)$; but in the question title it is listed as an assumption, whereas in the problem statement it is not assumed. This is all I was pointing out.

Comment: @User8128 Yeah I felt a little weird about that, just trying to shorten title a bit and I thought it was fine under the given assumptions. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As User8128 has pointed out, write $f = \lim \left( \frac{1}{2}(f_{n} + f) - \frac{1}{2}|f_{n} - f|\right)$. Then Fatou gives us

\begin{align}
\int_{E} f &\leq \liminf \int_{E} \left( \frac{1}{2}(f_{n} + f) - \frac{1}{2}|f_{n} - f|\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\liminf \int_{E} f_{n} + \frac{1}{2}\int_{E} f - \frac{1}{2}\limsup\int_{E} |f_{n} - f| \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{E} f + \frac{1}{2}\int_{E} f - \frac{1}{2}\limsup\int_{E} |f_{n} - f| \\
&\implies 0 = \limsup\int_{E} |f_{n} - f|, 
\end{align}

whence $\lim \int_{E} |f_{n} - f| = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Fatou's lemma and $f = \lim_{n\to \infty } \left( \frac 1 2( f_n + f) - \frac 1 2\lvert f_n - f\rvert\right).$

Comment: Okay, I've tried $\int_{E} f = \int_{E} \liminf (1/2 etc....) \leq \liminf \int_{E} (1/2 etc...) = \cdots$ and just ended up getting $\int_{E} f \leq \liminf \int_{E} f_{n}$, which is obvious. Is there something else you intended?

Comment: @Fred That's $\frac12(f_n+f)+\frac12|f_n-f|$, not $\frac12(f_n+f)-\frac12(f_n-f)$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for that, and actually I think it works either way: $\int_{E} f \leq \liminf \frac{1}{2}\int_{E} (f_{n} + f) + \liminf \frac{1}{2}\int_{E} |f_{n} - f| = \frac{1}{2} \int_{E} f + \frac{1}{2}\int_{E} f + \frac{1}{2} \liminf \int_{E} |f_{n} - f| \implies 0 = \liminf\int_{E} |f_{n} - f|$.

Comment: You're assuming that $\liminf(a_n+b_n)\le\liminf a_n+\liminf b_n$, which is not so. Also $\liminf\int|f_n-f|=0$ does not imply that $\int|f_n-f|\to0$.

Comment: Hint: It _is_ true that $\liminf (a_n+b_n)\le \liminf a_n+\limsup b_n$. (Also $\limsup b_n=-\liminf(-b_n)$.)